# Using "Will" for habits

Tags: grammar, tenses

I understand that "will" can be used to describe someone's habitual actions but how do I choose when to use will or present simple to describe habits.

Comment: Assuming it's describing current habits, there is no rule. Pick whichever sounds better to you. (1) *Everyday, he **will go** to the store.* (2) *Every day, he **goes** to the store.* They're both fine. If I had to personally choose one or the other at gunpoint, I'd probably lean slightly towards **goes**, only because it has no connotation of the future. But that's only me, and it would be a forced choice. (Different contexts could also change that choice.)

Comment: @JasonBassford is right.  After thinking about different contexts my conclusion is that if I want to emphasize the choice that is made I’ll is “will” if I am emphasizing the action then present simple:  if I’m planning where to ambush him then: “He goes to the store every day”  But if talking about his usual choices “Everyday he will go to the store if he wants fresh bread”